# Regex to convert a number to brazilian money with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I need to convert values like **100000** ​​to the Brazilian currency format (Real) **1.000,00** and I am using javascript.

That would be in this pattern.

```
0,00
1,00
10,00
100,00
1.000,00
```

I managed to create the decimals using this expression.

```
if (v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, '$1,00');
  }
```

Now I'm having trouble separating when I have values ​​above 1000,00 which would be 1.000,00.

I'm using the keyup that calls the function and writes the value in another field (Total) and this function that does all the work of converting the number to "Reais"

I did this function

```
String.prototype.formatMoney = function () {
  let v = this;
   
  if (v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, '$1,00');
  }

  v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, '$1,$20');
  v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, '$1,$2');
  console.log(v);

  return v;
};
```

My regex knowledge is weak, can somebody help me please?

Comment: You don't need to do all that. Just use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat)

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Randy
 I will read the articles and any questions I come back to here